# Is there any performance enhancement to passing data to the context object vs using graphQL query on page in Gatsby?

Tags: performance, graphql, gatsby

I'm wondering if there are any performance enhancements, or any benefits at all, to passing data via the context object for pages built using the createPages function in the gatsby-node file vs using a graphQL query in that template to get the same data.

I haven't noticed any differences, aside from cutting down some redundancy in code when you've already handled some incoming data in the gatsby-node file and you might as well pass it to the page.

But what about when you've made a query in the node file and you haven't done much with the data? Should you pass all that in via the context object? Or is it better to handle that in an explicit query in the page template itself?

Comment: Performance becomes noticeably different when you are having large number of nodes, thousand or more, and/or slow computer. But it's not about the performance only - I might be wrong, but I remember noticing that if you do the query in gatsby-node, it does not record that the page depends upon the data returned by the query - so when the data changes, the page will not be updated. It does not matter in the build mode, but in development mode, you usually will want to have a query in page template.

Comment: @artem - That makes sense and that is one thing I overlooked when asking the question: the node file is only used at build time. So obviously there are different use cases for querying in the node file vs the page file. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

The main proposal of using `gatsby-node.js` queries is to create pages dynamically based on query results. The obvious example is a blog; the idea is to query all the articles/posts from a blog, create pages from them via `createPages` API and pass through context some identifier value to query the parameters from each post (typically the slug). They are under the scope of [Gatsby Node API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/) and are not intended to play with data, just interact with them using the Node API. It is based on the server-side.

On the other hand, a standard page query (or `staticQuery`) is used to gather data based on the query, and use it directly on a page/component.

All kinds of GraphQL queries are triggered by the `develop`/`build`. In addition, they have different scopes, different proposals, and different usages so, the comparison isn't fair in this case.

Since Node APIs queries are promise-based, if they manage a humongous amount of data, may overload the `build`/`develop` time because they will block the rest of the compilation. So in this case, it will be better to add this load to page queries rather than Node API-based queries.